# Unable to start intent service via IMPLICIT intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, intentservice

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication"
         android:icon="@drawable/icon"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         >

 <service android:name=".MyService"
          android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.myapp.MyService.actionA"/>
            <action android:name="android.service.myapp.MyService.actionB"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          </intent-filter>

 </service>

</application>
```

If I use the following code, my service is launched:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
intent.setAction("android.service.myapp.MyService.actionA");
context.startService(intent);
```

But my service is not started if I launch it with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.service.myapp.MyService.actionA");
context.startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is insecure to use an "implicit" `Intent` to start or bind with a `Service`.  Starting with Lollipop, `bindService()` requires an explicit `Intent` (your first example where you specify the `Context` and `Class` for the `Service`.)  The behavior of `startService()` is undefined for implicit `Intent`s used to start a service.  From the documentation on `startService()`:

> The Intent should contain either contain the complete class name of a specific service implementation to start or a specific package name to target. If the Intent is less specified, it log a warning about this and which of the multiple matching services it finds and uses will be undefined.

If you use the explicit form, you can completely remove the `<intent-filter>` from the manifest: it is not needed.  If you need to specify some type of work to be done by the service via the `Intent`, consider using a extra within the `Intent`.